# Capturing intellisense input in Visual Studio, using envdte

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, envdte

I'm trying to develop a Visual Studio addon, which captures all the user input within the currently opened file.

So far, I could only find events which raise when the user types on the keyboard - which is fine, but it doesn't cover cases in which the intellisense is automatically inserting or changing/formatting the text (for example: auto-complete for class/method's name, or adding indententions in a new line after pressing the Enter key).

Is there any way to get a notice in the code at runtime, when this kind of events happen?